# Particles not responding to size changes

Tags: particles

(please excuse my noobiness, this could have a simple answer)
I can't get the particles to actually respond to the scale selector that is now nested under the Render tab. In older blender versions, there was a size slider under the emission tab. With the new update, I have found that it is now under render, no worries. The problem comes here, no matter how I change the scale slider, the particles don't change in size and just remain way too big.

[image: If you look on the right, under the RENDER drop down, The scale is at 1 and the particle size]

[image: The scale at 20 and the size is no different]

[image: Again no difference when the scale is at 200]

Each time I played the simulation again after changing the size.
Anyone got any ideas?

Comment: This may have to do with the fact that you are in solid view mode, although I have noticed some problems with particle rendering in EEVEE that required some settings changes. Have you tried viewing the simulation in rendered view?

Answer (score 1):

Set *Render As* to Object and link it to a new created object (looks like you need a sphere). Path (Hair) and Halo (Emission) do not contain any geometry data so you can't scale them.